# AngularJS ng-class with two classes and shorten ES6 if

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have this:

```
ng-class="
 filter.page == $index ? 'btn-dark' : 'btn-outline-secondary'
"
```

Which works.

However, I want to add more classes, depends on different `IF`s

like this:

```
ng-class="
 filter.page == $index ? 'btn-dark' : 'btn-outline-secondary';
 $root.t.direction=='rtl' ? 'ml-2' : 'mr-2'
"
```

But only the last is getting applied.

Comment: It's all explained in the documentation of ngClass. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: You can't have a `;` in there. Use `[…, …].join(" ")`.

Comment: @Bergi no need for a join: ngClass accepts an array of class names as argument.

Comment: @MarcusHöglund please refer and read my question again. The question is not duplicate it's a complete different question.

Comment: Also see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the conditions between `[]` as an array:

```
ng-class="
  [filter.page == $index ? 'btn-dark' : 'btn-outline-secondary',
  $root.t.direction=='rtl' ? 'ml-2' : 'mr-2']
"
```